# jQuery: performing some action before form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, maps, geocode

I have a page with a single form on it. The form contains a text box and a submit button.

When the form is submitted, either by clicking the button, or by pressing enter in the textbox, I want to do a lookup (in this case, geocoding a postcode using Bing Maps), and then submit the form to the server, as usual.

My current approach is to add a handler for the submit event to the one-and-only form, and then call submit() when I've finished, but I can't get this to work, and haven't been able to debug the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        var postcode = $.trim($("#Postcode").val());
        if (postcode.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        var baseUrl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/";
        var apiKey = "myKey";
        var url = baseUrl + postcode + "?key=" + apiKey + "&jsonp=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
            if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
                var location = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
                $("#latitude").val(location[0]);
                $("#longitude").val(location[1]);
                $("form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` is your friend here. You are basically experiencing the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165254/browser-wont-set-cookie-from-an-onclick-event/6165296#6165296). The form is submitted before the actual ajax request can be done. You need to halt the form submission, then do the ajax, and then do the form submission. If you don't put some stops in there, it'll just run through it and the only thing it'll have time to do is to submit the form.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (event) {

// prevent default form submit
    event.preventDefault();
            var postcode = $.trim($("#Postcode").val());
            if (postcode.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }


            var baseUrl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/";
            var apiKey = "myKey";
            var url = baseUrl + postcode + "?key=" + apiKey + "&jsonp=?";
            $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
                if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
                    var location = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
                    $("#latitude").val(location[0]);
                    $("#longitude").val(location[1]);
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Howevern, when you put the `preventDefault` in there you can't continue the form submission with `$('form').submit();` anymore. You need to send it as an ajax request, or define a conditional to the `preventDefault`.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var submitForReal = false;
        $("form").submit(function (event) {

            var postcode = $.trim($("#Postcode").val());
            if (postcode.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }
    // prevent default form submit
    if(!submitForReal){
    event.preventDefault();
    }else{



            var baseUrl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/";
            var apiKey = "myKey";
            var url = baseUrl + postcode + "?key=" + apiKey + "&jsonp=?";
            $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
                if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
                    var location = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
                    $("#latitude").val(location[0]);
                    $("#longitude").val(location[1]);
                    submitForReal = true;
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You would also need to exclude any code that you only wanted to run the first time as you probably would want to run `$.getJSON(...)` again.

Comment: Quite right, modified the rest to be only run under the else conditional. Although, it shouldn't be running the ajax on a form submit anyway, but now at least it won't even attempt to do it.